# hibernate object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Im confused with the JPA manytoone relationship, i have a class 'judgement' which has many 'judges', when i tried to store a judgement instance into postgres db, it threw error message as:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.dyihi.evaluation.model.Judgement.judge -> com.dyihi.evaluation.model.User
```

the judgement class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JUDGEMENTS")
public class Judgement implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7049957706738879274L;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User judge;
```

and my service class:

```
public Long store(Judgement judgement) throws RepositoryException {

        EntityManager em = null;
        EntityTransaction tx = null;
        try {
            em = _emf.createEntityManager();
            tx = em.getTransaction();
            tx.begin();
            em.persist(judgement);
            tx.commit();
            return judgement.getId();
        }
        finally {
            if (tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
                em = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

and in my db i have tables Judgement and User, do i need to create a table as Judgement_User for the ManyToOne relationship?

Comment: your code suggests that a judge has many judgements, not the other way around

Comment: are you creating both a new Judgement and a new User at the same time?

Comment: @kem: user is created by admin user, when user login to the system, they need to do judgements, so I only create new Judgement and assign that existing user as the judge of that judgement, not create both at the same time. also if i wanna to delete any judgement, user should be untouched at all.

Comment: @kem: you are right, i mean a judge has many judgements.

Answer (score 0):

First, if, as you stated, you are looking for a judgement to have many judges, you have things backward.  As kem suggests in his comment, the way you have it coded now *Many* judgements have *One* judge, the inverse being that *One* judge may have *Many* judgements.

In response to your question, the judge that is associated with the judgement you are attempting to save has not itself been saved.  Your cascade definition doesn't allow the persist to cascade into the judge, therefore JPA has no choice but to throw the exception.  You can change the cascade definition, or manually save the judge.  If the judge is persistent, but detached then you may need to merge it first to reattach it to the entity manager.